# Localization for CONVERT

Tags: t-sql, localization

I need to join two tables based on columns with different types. The first column is a `nvarchar(50)` and the second column if of type `float`. The nvarchar-column contains a string representation of the float value, but written in german localization, which means, that the comma is used as decimal separator.

Example: The float 26.1 ist represented as 26,1 in the nvarchar column.

I tried `JOIN ... ON firstcolumn = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), secondcolumn)` which works for all numbers without fraction. Columns with fraction are translated into "26.1" which obviously doesn't match "26,1".

Using `SET LANGUAGE German` didn't work.

Is there a way to use german localization for the CONVERT statement, so that the comma instead of the dot is used? Or do i have to use `REPLACE` to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `REPLACE` as

```
firstcolumn = CAST(REPLACE(secondcolumn, ',', '.') as float)
```

**BUT** be very careful when comparing floating point types, sometimes better to use this construction:

```
ABS(firstcolumn - CAST(REPLACE(secondcolumn, ',', '.') as float)) < @epsilon
```

where @epsilon is acceptable error, say = 0.001

Comment: I will compare on the string representation, so I dont have to handle the float problem. Thanks anyway.